# Feature rich CMS/Blog to use with codeigniter app

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, drupal, content-management-system

I am building a site where the main content will be news/articles. But it would also have other modules like jobs, listings, user profiles written in codeigniter.

If it was only the articles, I would have chosen wordpress/joomla for my site. So my question is, which of feature-rich CMS/Blog system (Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, etc.) is easy to integrate with an codeigniter application. The CMS will only be used for the articles/news.

I don't want to reinvent the whole wheel by writing my own CMS in codeigniter. Want to use something which is already available and used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will be good among the other all.

Can refer to

http://philpalmieri.com/2009/06/codeigniter-and-wordpress-play-well-together/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com) which is build in codeigniter